# Asp.Net MVC Core 2 - Using ViewBag on _Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to dynamically set some properties such as `RootCSSUrl` on the view bag and read them on `_Layout.cshtml` page.

So far I tried to do it by using a "BaseController" (and all controllers inherit from it) and setting such properties on the constructor as `ViewBag.RootCSSUrl = isDevelopment ? "blob.mysite.com":"blob.mysite.com";`.

The problem is that on the _layout rendering, this value is always null...

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it by creating an global action filter as in https://damienbod.com/2015/09/15/asp-net-5-action-filters/

the actionFilter code is quite simple:

```
public class CommonViewBagInitializerActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
#if DEBUG
        ((BaseController)context.Controller).ViewBag.RootBlobURL = "";
#else
        ((Controller)context.Controller).ViewBag.RootBlobURL = "https://blob.mysite.com";
#endif
    }
}
```

the registration of the filter is:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            config.Filters.Add(new CommonViewBagInitializerActionFilter());
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please include the importants parts from that link in your answer, or show the action filter code you ended up with.

Comment: @poke done! check if it's clear... if not, how can i improve it?

Comment: I don't see the need for BaseController cast in your code. context.Controller has access to ViewBag. The way you have it now, your filter will work only on controllers that inherit from BaseController. Otherwise you're get an exception...

Comment: @Marko tks! i fixed it!